# Overlaped two images with z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have one image inside a div element:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="images/products/product1.jpg" />
</div>
```

I want to add a second image named *frame.png*, but not like a background image!

```
<img src="images/products/frame.png" />
```

And I want to overlap image *product1.jpg* with *frame.png*, that way it will look like *frame.png* is over *prduct1.jpg*.

Is that possible with z-index, but not as a background image, because I'm using it in a responsive design?

Finaly I want to get something like:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="images/products/product1.jpg" />
    <img src="images/products/frame.png" />
</div>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at _responsive images_. **Stacking** the images over eachother in a responsive design is something I'd recommend _against_! I've bad experiences with a design concept using this approach to position images where the whole needs to be responsive. It'll cost you lots of time on little changes throughout the design process.

Comment: You need to add some css. set your div to `position:relative` and your images to `position:absolute`. Then the pictures are over each other and you can adjust the position with left,right,top,bottom and also z-index will then work.

Comment: _Btw:_ [**Be _more_ specific**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Give us more details and context, so we can provide a useful answer. What have you tried? **Show some CSS!**

Comment: I have made it like this :)                  <div class="single-product">
      
 <img style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" src="images/products/product1.jpg" />
     <img src="images/assets/frame.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"/>                       
                         
                        </div><!--end of .single-product -->

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the porduct1.jpg has #product id, and frame.png #frame id
Now,

what if

```
.full-width {position:absolute;}
#product, #frame {position:relative;}
```

and in addition you set top and left for #product according to #frame width.., + z-index

Comment: I would not make the wrapper just so absolute. That could destroy the outer design very easily. it is better to make it relative.

Comment: that's right. My mistake. Messed up the containers. That was exactly what i wanted to say! :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all set div to `position:relative` and your images to `position:absolute` in your css. Then set the z-index for e.g. if you want image 1 to be above image 2 then set its z-index higher than image 2.

Comment: **Congrats** to your _1st answer_ here on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="full-width">
    <img class="imgone" src="http://s23.postimg.org/b2h2rz457/image.png" />
    <img class="imgtwo" src="http://s13.postimg.org/jlyzyofkn/image.png" />
</div>

.full-width {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
img.imgone {
    position:absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
img.imgtwo {
    position:absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

[CHECK OUT THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcwbF/)

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:relative` for `full-width`, give `position:absolute` for inside `img`. Align each other using their respective top,left.. attributes.  Use z-index on whichever image you want to show. I think that will work. But to show images overlapping in a responsive design is a bad idea.